# Unable to open InfoPath forms with large attachments in browser

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

We have been running a infopath solution on SharePoint 2010 for a couple of years now. The form is rendered in the browser, but when the attachments are large in size (seems like a ~10MB limit for the form), the system would not allow the user to edit the form in the browser. Instead the browser pops up with a dialog say: "What to you want to do with [FILENAME].xml? Open | Save | Save as.

Forms less than 10MB renders perfectly in the browser

Are anyone able to clarify what is going on and how we can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest offloading form attachments to a library.  This will make the forms a lot more responsive.

You will want to try increasing the upload limit for your Web App.
Also look at your InfoPath Form Services data connection timeout settings.  Currently have my max connection set at 200,000 milliseconds.

(Central Admin --> General Application Settings --> Configure InfoPath Form Services)

If that doesn't work, you will need to increase your IIS limits.

Blog post that covers these topics:
http://angler.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/increase-the-sharepoint-2010-upload-file-size-limit/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunatelly, it didn't resolve the issue. It does not seems to be related to the max file size in SharePoint as the forms have already been saved in the form library. The form size only seems to be a problem when editing the form in browser mode.

I have raised all settings in the "Configure InfoPath Form Services" page without any luck.